# Setting up advanced Python logging

Tags: python, logging

I'd like to use logging for my modules, but I'm not sure how to design the following requirements:

- normal logging levels (info, error, warning, debug) but also some additional more verbose debug levels
- logging messages can have different types; some are meant for the developer, some are meant for the user; those types go to different outputs
- errors should go to `stderr`
- I also need to keep track which module/function/code line wrote a debug message so that I can activate or deactivate individual debug messages in a configuration
- I need to keep track if errors occured at all to eventually execute a `sys.exit()` at the end of the program
- all messages should go to `stdout` until the loggers are set up

I've read the logging documentation, but I'm not sure what's the most streamline way to use the logging module with the requirements above (how to use concept of Logger, Handler, Filter, ...). Can you point out an idea to set this up? (e.g. write module with two loggers 'user', 'developer'; derive from `Logger`; do `getLogger(__name__)`; keep error flag like this,... etc.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### 1) Adding more verbose debug levels.

Have you thought this through?

Take a look about what the [doc](http://docs.python.org/py3k/howto/logging.html#custom-levels) says:

> Defining your own levels is possible, but **should not be necessary**, as the existing levels have been chosen on the basis of practical experience. However, if you are convinced that you need custom levels, **great care should be exercised** when doing this, and **it is possibly a very bad idea to define custom levels if you are developing a library**. That's because if multiple library authors all define their own custom levels, there is a chance that the logging output from such multiple libraries used together will be difficult for the using developer to control and/or interpret, because a given numeric value might mean different things for different libraries.

Take also a look at [**When to use logging**](http://docs.python.org/py3k/howto/logging.html#when-to-use-logging), there are two very good tables explaining when to use what.

Anyway, if you think you'll need those extra logging levels, take a look at: [`logging.addLevelName()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/logging.html#logging.addLevelName).

#### 2) Some logging messages for the developer, and some for the user

Use different loggers family with different handlers. At the base of each family set [`Logger.propagate`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.propagate) to `False`.

#### 3) Errors should go to `stderr`

This already happen by default with [`StreamHandler`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.StreamHandler):

> class logging.StreamHandler(stream=None)
>
> > Returns a new instance of the StreamHandler class. If stream is specified, the instance will use it for logging output; otherwise, *sys.stderr* will be used.

#### 4) Keep track of the source of a log message

Get Loggers with different names, and in your [Formatter](http://docs.python.org/py3k/howto/logging.html#formatters) use format strings with `%(name)s`.

#### 5) All messages should go to `stdout` until the loggers are set up

The setup of your logging system should be one of the very first things to do, so I don't really see what this means. If you need to send messages to stdout use `print` as it should be and already explained in [When to use logging](http://docs.python.org/py3k/howto/logging.html#when-to-use-logging).

Last advice: *carefully* read the [**Logging Cookbook**](http://docs.python.org/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-cookbook) as it covers pretty well what you need.

---

#### *From the comment*:  How would I design to have output to different sources and also filter my module?

I wouldn't filter in the first place, filers are hard to maintain and if they are all in one place that place will have to hold too much information. Every module should get abd set its own Logger (with its own handlers or filters) using or not its parent setting.

Very quick example:

```
# at the very beginning
root = logging.getLogger()
fallback_handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
root.addHandler(fallback_handler)

# first.py
first_logger = logging.getLogger('first')
first_logger.parent = False
# ... set 'first' logger as you wish
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger('first.Foo')
    def baz(self):
        self.logger.info("I'm in baz")

# second.py
second_logger = logging.getLogger('first.second') # to use the same settings

# third.py
abstract_logger = logging.getLogger('abs')
abstract_logger.parent = False
# ... set 'abs' logger
third_logger = logging.getLogger('abs.third')
# ... set 'abs.third' particular settings

# fourth.py
fourth_logger = logging.getLogger('abs.fourth')
# [...]
```

Comment: Personally I've always found a single 'Debug' level to be insufficient. Several log packages also have a 'Trace' level which can be handy for very verbose output.

Comment: 1) For debugging I want to introduce very verbose messages (e.g. within loops) which I want to activate on demand; 2) I'm thinking about setting up `getLogger("user."+__name__)` for modules because I also want to filter the output by module; Or is there another solution?; 3) I actually want to go INFO to stdout and ERROR to stderr; for the moment I set up two handlers with custom filters; other suggestions?; 4) I need to filter by this; 5) I want a stdout fallback in case handlers are missing; this fallback should be deactivated as soon as handlers are set

Comment: @Kylotan: TBH I never stumbled in a trace level, but it make sense. A good logging system can save you hours of debugging, but the problem is that with a too verbose logging design among all that noise is hard to tell what is important.

Comment: @Gerenuk: It seems to me that you're trying to filter too much. Get a Logger to "inherit" from some basic set and then build it as you need for that module/function. An info to stdout it should be printed, why go through all the logging? It's just mixing things up and it's over complicated. Why handlers should be missing, is there an actual problem?

Comment: No sure what you mean. How would I design/inhert logger to have both, output to different sources and also filter my module? I'm not printing because I might deliver logging to various source only one of which is stdout. Handlers might be missing because smaller test programs might not instantiate the project logging to files. In that case I want stdout as a fallback.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas!!! So I can `addLevelName` however can I also create a corresponding function `.debug_verbose()`? What would you suggest if the program should execute `sys.exit(1)` depending on whether there was an error? Maybe a fake Hanlder which sets a global variable?

Comment: @Gerenuk: Maybe that `.` in front of `debug_verbose()` is a typo, but you don't need to at that as a method. Call `logger.setLevel(5)` or whatever it is, and if you want you can put that inside a function which get the nedded loggers. About your `sys.exit(1)` I really disagree with what you're trying to do, loggers are for logging not for closing your script or handling exceptions.

Comment: The logger doesn't call exit. But it needs to provide information for other objects to judge which exit status to set.